# beginner c code- trouble with two dimensional array

Tags: c

I'm simply trying to print this matrix, and to be honest I have no idea why i'm getting certain compiler errors.I am getting "formal parameter incomplete" and both M and N undeclared errors.

```
int print_matrix(int*[][]);

int main()
{
  int N = rand() % 10;
  int M= rand() % 10;
  int matrix[N][M];
  int n; 
  int m;

  for (n=0; n<N; n++)
  {
    for (m=0; m<M; m++)
    {
      matrix[N][M]= rand()%20 +(-10);
    }
  }
  print_matrix(&matrix);

  return 0;
}

int print_matrix(int *matrix[N][M])
{   
  int m;
  int n;

  for (n=0; n<N; n++)
  {
    for (m=0; m<M; m++)
    {
      printf("%2d", matrix[n][m]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the address of an array, the array name is already the address.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Do you want a matrix of ints or a matrix of pointers to ints?

Comment: `N` and `M` are not global , therefore not visible in function . Pass them to function from calling function .

Answer (score 5):

You have a few mistakes in your code, the most important is that you don't need to pass the address of the array, and if you do so you should handle it correctly in the `print_matrix()` function.

The following code fixes all the issues

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10
int print_matrix(int N, int M, int matrix[N][M]);

int
main(void)
{
    int N = rand() % SIZE;
    int M = rand() % SIZE;
    int matrix[N][M];
    int n;
    int m;

    for (n = 0 ; n < N ; n++)
    {
        for (m = 0 ; m < M ; m++)
            matrix[n][m]= rand() % 20 + (-10);
    }
    print_matrix(N, M, matrix);
    return 0;
}

int
print_matrix(int N, int M, int matrix[N][M])
{
    int m;
    int n;
    for (n = 0 ; n < N ; n++)
    {
        for (m = 0 ; m < M ; m++)
            printf("%5d ", matrix[n][m]);
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I now explain what I fixed

1. Pass the number of rows and columns to `print_matrix()`.
2. You had another error when assigning matrix elements, you used upper case `N` and `M`, hence you were always accessing the element after the last in the array.
3. Remove the `&` and the `*` from the function call and it's defenition respectively, the array is automatically converted to a pointer when it's the argument of a function, try `sizeof(matrix)` and you can verify that it's the same as `sizeof(void *)`.

You can do this

```
int
print_matrix(int N, int M, int matrix[N][M])
```

because you also can do this

```
int N = rand() % SIZE;
int M = rand() % SIZE;
int matrix[N][M];
```

and viceversa.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is an exercise in using and understanding pointers however from my book so I would like to use them. Do you know how that would be done?

Comment: Yes of course I know. But why doesn't your book help?